# C# To Dynamically Generate HTML Table

Tags: c#, html, stringbuilder

I am attempting to Dynamically generate an HTML Table.  What I am after is to have a header row and a second row of textboxes under the header row (all aligned horizontally across the page).  I attempted this syntax - however it ignores the values that are selected in the checkboxlist, and the textboxes for input are stacked on top of each other instead of horizontal.

Can someone right the errors in my ways?

```
    protected void btnBullDozer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
    var columnname = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
    {
        columnname = item.Text;

        sb.Append("<table>");
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.Append("<th>Sponsor Level</th>");
        sb.Append("<th>" + item.Selected + "</th>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    var cm = string.Empty;
    int z = 1;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
    {
        cm = item.Text;
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field " + z + "\"></td>");
        z = z + 1;
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");

    mask.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

Hypothetical of what my desired grid should look like - let's say that the user selected 4 options from the checkboxlist then I would want 5 headers (Sponsor Level, and the names selected) then one row with 5 empty textboxes underneath for the data entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move  `tr` and `table` out of `for loop`
Also, since you need following:

**Input from you**

> I need header row going horizontal across the page (based off the selections from the checkboxlist) then for each header I need an input box under the header, only one row.

Changed your logic as follows:

```
protected void btnBullDozer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
var columnname = string.Empty;
sb.Append("<table>");
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<th>Sponsor Level</th>");
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
{
    //This loop will genrate a horizontal header for all checkbox items
    columnname = item.Text;        
    sb.Append("<th>" + item.Selected + "</th>");
}
sb.Append("</tr>"); //empty td for Sponsor Level header

var cm = string.Empty;
int z = 1;
sb.Append("<tr><td></td>");
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
{
    //This will generate a item under each header
    cm = item.Text;
    //if you want input for only selected items in checkbox uncomment following line
    /*if(!item.Selected)
      {
        sb.Append("<td></td>");
      }
      else
      {*/
       sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field " + z + "\"></td>");
//    }

    z = z + 1;
}
sb.Append("</tr>");

sb.Append("</table>");

mask.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

> Note: First forLoop will generate headers for all checkbox items. Second for loop will generate inputbox for all checkbox items. Its not very good logic though, we can refactor it a little to use only one loop

Comment: can you show full syntax?  And keep the one outside the loop or remove it?

Comment: Using the updated code, the text boxes are still stacked vertical on top of each other

Comment: Sorry.. your Table also needs to be out of loop.. edited now

Comment: moving the table outside the loop everything is still horizontal

Comment: Can you add picture of output in your questions? code seems okay now

Comment: Added image to fully display - it is only showing SponsorLevel true or SponsorLevel false instead of the actual selected text, but I will hopefuly be able to resolve that :)

Comment: According to your logic this output is correct.. First loop will generate all headers first.. and second loop will only generate input fields.. How you need it ? only 1 header and all textbox under that header?

Comment: I need header row going horizontal across the page (based off the selections from the checkboxlist) then for each header I need an input box under the header, only one row.  Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164276/discussion-between-surjit-sd-and-bojack-horseman).

Answer (score 2):

Think about the logic of HTML.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So you want to:

```
<table>
<tr>

First foreach loop for the headings
    <th>
    Text
    </th>
End Loop

</tr>
<tr>

Second foreach loop for the values
    <td>
    Value
    </td>
End loop

</tr>
</table>
```

That is how I understand your comments. I know others have provided actual code but I wanted to go back to basics of HTML construct. When you have that clear in your mind you can convert it to logic to create it dynamically with loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void btnBullDozer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
    var columnname = string.Empty;

        sb.Append("<table>");
        sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
    {
        columnname = item.Text;

        sb.Append("<th>Sponsor Level</th>");
        sb.Append("<th>" + item.Selected + "</th>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    var cm = string.Empty;
    int z = 1;

        sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxtest.Items)
    {
        cm = item.Text;
        sb.Append("<td colspan="2"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field " + z + "\"></td>");
        z = z + 1;
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");

    mask.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: and comment out the <tr> I have outside of the for each loop or leave it in play?  Can you show full syntax?

Comment: This stacks everything vertical on the page - not horizontal

Comment: @BoJackHorseman My foul. So, you need 2 rows, one with headers (th), one with values (td). Edited again, hope this is a solution

Comment: Yes - that is what I am after.  But for some reason syntax is not adding header based off selection from checkboxlist?

Comment: try with columnname instead item.Selected.

Comment: That will display all, not just the checked ones

Comment: item.IsChecked.Value (something like that). WinForms, WPF, ... ?

Comment: This is C#/Asp.Net webforms

Comment: how look your Checkbox tag? have some value declared? display some more code into your question